# Quaternion to matrix rotation only one axis

Tags: math

I have a quaternion that contains the rotation of the three axes (x, y, z) at the same time.

I want to convert this quaternion to a rotation matrix but only the rotation on the Y axis of the quaternion or of any of the other axes, without all three at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible route:

- Transform unit vectors X=(1,0,0) and Z=(0,0,1) by the quaternion
- Call these rotated vectors (x0,x1,x2) and (z0,z1,z2)
- If the rotation would have been purely around Y, we would have:

  - (x0,x1,x2) = (cos(theta), 0, sin(theta))
  - (z0,z1,z2) = (-sin(theta), 0, cos(theta))
  - not used is (y0,y1,y2) = (0, 1, 0)
- so, calculate

  - c = (x0+z2) / 2
  - and s = (x2-z0) / 2
- then normalize to get c<sup>2</sup> + s<sup>2</sup> equal to 1

  - norm = sqrt(c * c + s * s)
  - if norm != 0:

    - c = c / norm
    - s = s / norm
    - (if the norm would be zero, there is not much we can do)
- the angle would be atan2(c, s)
- the rotation matrix would be [[c,0,-s],[0,1,0],[s,0,c]]

Comment: Thanks for your help, friend.